# EntityManager.persist not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

I have a test servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin()
        DBManager.getInstance().eraseDB();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        if(DBManager.getInstance().createUser("first", "second"))
            writer.print("done.");
        else
            writer.print("failed.");
        em.getTransaction().commit();

    }
```

the method `eraseDB` is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void eraseDB(){
        EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("select u from User u");
        List<User> list = q.getResultList(); 
        for(User u : list){
            em.remove(u);   
        }       
    }
```

while the method `createUser` is:

```
public static synchronized boolean createUser(String username, String password) {
        EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("select u from User u");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> list = q.getResultList();
        if(list.size() > 0)
            return false;
        User u = new User();
        u.setPassword(password);
        u.setUsername(username);
        em.persist(u);
        return true;
    }
```

After the servlet call I get true from `createUser` method but the datastore is empty.

Why is `persist` not working? What am I doing wrong?
Any other advice about this architecture is welcome, thanks.

Comment: You start and commit a transaction using a first entity manager, but you're persisting using a second, different one.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. But if I put a transaction begin/commit before/after persist and another one before/after the for loop in eraseDB, there is a problem with concurrency (keeping F5 pressed I get exceptions or I get two elements into the DB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Jb nizet's answer:
When you specify explicitly a transaction ( with `em.getTransaction.begin/commit/rollback`) you cannot begin a second transaction if the first was not commit or rollback. In you code you should keep your transaction into each DbManager's methods, like that:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException {
        EntityManager em = Emf.get().createEntityManager();
        DBManager.getInstance().eraseDB(em);
        if(DBManager.getInstance().createUser(em,"first", "second"))
            writer.print("done.");
        else
            writer.print("failed.");

    }
```

---

```
public void eraseDB(EntityManager em){
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u");
    List<User> list = q.getResultList();
    Try{
        em.getTransaction().begin(); 
        for(User u : list){
           em.remove(u);   
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }   
}
```

---

```
public static synchronized boolean createUser(EntityManager em, String username, String password) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u");
        List<User> list = q.getResultList();
        if(list.size() > 0)
            return false;
        User u = new User();
        u.setPassword(password);
        u.setUsername(username);
        Try{
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(u);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            return false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to make em as attribute of DBManager because I don't like to pass it as parameter to every single method.

Comment: Yes it's sure, but I didn't see your business class. Put into your business class your EM as static final and VOLATILE to make your EM threadsafe

Comment: Thank you, just two questions: is it necessary the static keyword if the DBManager is a singleton? is it necessary the volatile keyword if all the DBManager methods are synchronized? (an optional third question: is better volatile than synchronized in this case?). Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry I said a mistake, the static keyword isn't necessary, just declare your EM as private final ( final because your EM won't change). For your DbManager getinstance method you can use different method to instance your DbManager class, report you at this page http://java.dzone.com/articles/singleton-design-pattern. I hope that will help you.